# PHP storefront project select a category

Tags: php, html

I have this project to do for my web programming class, here are the instructions:

*You are building a store that sells hats, shoes and watches. The customer:
Logs in
Selects a product category
You display all products (image and price) for that category. Also display a select list for the quantity of each product to be purchased.
After the customer makes selections display an invoice with a line for each product sold with price, quantity and total cost for that product. Total cost at bottom.*

I have done the login page correctly and the html for the "choose a category" page but I'm having trouble displaying the products based on what the user chooses. There is a delimited file/database we have to work with but we CANNOT use sql. I can't stress this enough, no SQL whatsoever.

So when you click on "shoes", "hat", or "watch", it should take you to the page that only shows shoes, hats or watches. We have to do this in a php page. This is all I have so far:

```
$catalogfile = $fopen("data/catalog.dat","r"); //Getting the file;

$category = $_GET[cat];
```

And this is the html of the page it's connected to:

```
    <form id = '' name = '' action='project2.php' method='post' class = ''>

        <a href = 'project2?cat=hat' id = 'hat' class = ''>HAT</a><br>

        <a href = 'project2?cat=shoes' id = 'shoes' class = ''>SHOES</a><br>

        <a href = 'project2?cat=watch' id = 'watch' class = ''>WATCH</a>

    </form>
```

I am incredibly confused, I seriously have no idea what to do next and I've been staring at this small bit of code for about two hours. Most of this isn't in the textbook and this is our final so I can't ask the professor for help.

Comment: Can you put every product and category in seperate files? like a hats.php, shoes.php and a watches.php link to those pages? Just trying to get your thinking proces more clear.

Answer (score 0):

First, your form has its method attribute set to *post*. Therefore, your PHP script will return null at $_GET[cat] (which, btw, will crash because *cat* is a symbol--probably undefined--you want *"cat"* as a string).

Your next step is to figure out what to do with that information on the server; then, provide an appropriate response.